# Utility Types or dynamic Type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how to make dynamic type of function in python like typescript:

this is example that I mean

```
function useRef<T>(val:T): T {
    return val
}
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types?

Comment: hay, thank for your link reference. I'm relatively new in python, and I look for similar thing as typescript or another type language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python **is** a dynamic language, nothing is statically typed and *everything* is a reference. This is the spirit of Python, you should take a look at the documentation.

As pointed out in a comment you can use Python3 typing module if you want some flavor of typing.